# Trying to use low_replace inside an EE Multi Select field

Tags: parsing, low

I have a channel for scholarships with a a Multi Select field with a list of schools. Each scholarship is available to certain schools, so I want to create a div with a class for each school, so I can use jQuery to hide/show scholarships available for each school using select. The options are hard coded right now.

```
<select>
<option value="Example1-High-School">Example1 High School</option>
<option value="Example2-High-School">Example2 High School</option>
</select>
```

What I am getting

```
<div class="Example1 High School Example2 High School">
 More information about the scholarship
</div>
```

What I want

```
<div class="Example1-High-School Example2-High-School">
 More information about the scholarship
</div>
```

Here is my template code:

```
            {exp:channel:entries channel="scholarships" dynamic="off" sort="asc" orderby="title"}
            <div class="{schools}{exp:low_replace find='SPACE' replace='-'}{item}{/exp:low_replace} {/schools}">
                <h2>{title}</h2>
                <h3>Schools:</h3>
                <ul>{schools}
                    <li>{item}</li>
{/schools}      </ul>
                {description}
            </div>
            {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
class="{exp:low_replace find="SPACE|," replace="-|SPACE" multiple="yes"}{schools backspace="1"}{item},{/schools}{/exp:low_replace}"
```